# Server docker installs jenkins, config.xml cannot be modified, and the port cannot be accessed

Tags: docker, jenkins, cicd

### Problem Description

The server docker installs jenkins, everything runs normally, but the browser cannot access it.

### Problem background

Manually pull the jenkins image and create the container:

Manually pull the jenkins image and create the container:

```bash
docker run -d --name jenkins -p 8088:8080 -p 50000:50000 --restart=always -v /home/jenkins_volume/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

> The Jenkins version is the latest LTS, deployed using docker, and the data volume is mounted.
> The system does not have a firewall enabled

The following is what docker ps -a displays
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8G7T.png)
The following is the docker logs container display
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qam1.png)
Native curl localhost:8088 jumps to /login normally √
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gx5Ar.png)
Local curl test public network IP failed ×
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5bRb.png)

~~ Please help the gods, i will appreciate for it! ~~

### What has been tried

1. Modify useSecurity in config.xml (but it cannot be modified, and the modification will automatically become invalid after restarting)
   According to the blog https://juejin.cn/post/7072251086463057957
   As mentioned, it may be that Jenkins has set the cert credentials and needs to be manually modified to false in config.xml.
   Then I tried to modify the config.xml under jenkins_home mounted on the host, and then restarted.
   As a result, after the restart, the config.xml under jenkins_home mounted on the host has not been modified.
2. According to 1, use docker cp to copy the directory into the container

After modifying the host's config.xml, I executed docker cp

```bash
docker cp /home/jenkins_volume/jenkins_home 容器id:/var/jenkins_home
```